# Query table with composite primary key, excluding specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
product_id | category
---------------------
1          | A
1          | B
2          | A
3          | B
```

I would like to know which unique ids belong to category A but NOT category B.
In the example above, only `id: 2` would be a valid result

I came up with this which does not work as intended:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE category = 'A' AND category <> 'B'
GROUP BY id
```

A valid approach would be to use a subquery

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE category = 'A' 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT id
                 FROM table
                 WHERE category = 'B')
```

Is it possible to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.category = 'B'
WHERE t1.category = 'A' and t2.id IS NULL
```

Another way is with grouping:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE category IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(category) = 'A'
```

Comment: thank you! I knew I was missing something but couldn't find the appropriate terms to use to find the answer myself

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(category = 'A') > 0
   AND SUM(category = 'B') = 0;
```

or:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE category IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(category = 'B') = 0;
```